# Grandchild instanceof Parent returns false

Tags: java, javafx

Can't figure out why my code returns false when checking relations between below classes.

```
public abstract class Controller {
    public Controller(){};
    public abstract void init();
}

public class OperationController<T> extends Controller {
    public OperationController(){};
    public void init() {
    // here something happens
    };
}

public class DailyOperationController extends OperationController<DailyOperation> {
    public DailyOperationController (){};
    public void init() {
    // here something happens
    };
}
```

What I do is to check if given class is an instance of Controller class and then call init() method:

```
//somewhere in Main class
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource(panel.getFxmlPath()));
    if(loader.getController() instanceof Controller)
        ((Controller) loader.getController()).init();
//somewhere in Main class
```

If-condition returns true when checking OperationController object and false when checking DailyOperationController object. I suspect the main problem is my inability to understand abstract keyword concept, so I will be grateful for every help. I want to be able to init either OperationController object and DailyOperationController.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `loader.getController()` is a `Controller` and, more importantly, that it is not `null`? From a logical point, the code should work if `loader.getController()` returns a `Controller`.

Comment: Yeah, It is a NullPointerException. Loader loads with no problem but Parent is null. Searching for 15 minutes but no idea how to fix it. The reason must be common.

Comment: Found the bane. I used same structure for the view (OperationController-related FXML file includes DailyOperationController-related FXML file) and when I call controller OperationController and does its init(), DailyOperationController init() isn't invoked.

Comment: Without you calling a `FXMLLoader.load` instance method(or you using `setController` with a non-`null` parameter), the `controller` property is `null`. `instanceof` yields false regardless of what type it's used with in that case. Since you not pass any info as parameter to `init` or don't invoke any other method passing info before, why not simply use `initialize`???

Comment: Abandoned Initializable interface because everything I want to do must be set after scene creation.

Comment: Fabian, the problem occured on my wish. Using own initialization method I simply forgot to connect every relation as I desire it to work. Not enogh time to fix it all together but the most importan clue I have already have. I may say the problem is solved.